# Sort vector of objects for binary search

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, jquery-ui-sortable, binary-search

I have the following class:

```
struct EdgeExtended {
    int neighborNodeId;
    int weight;
    int arrayPointer;
    bool isCrossEdge;

};
```

I want to have a vector of such objects, sort it by neighborNodeId. Then I want to search for a particular neighborNodeId and return a reference to the found object inside the vector by binary search. Previously I used a map for that, so it was something like that:

```
map<int, EdgeExtended> neighbours;
.....

auto it = neighbours.find(dnodeId);
if (it != neighbours.end()) {
    edgeMap = it->second; 
}
```

Instead of

```
map<int, EdgeExtended> neighbours;
```

I want to have

```
vector<EdgeExtended> neighbours;
```

and retain as much as the old code the same.

I want to benchmark if the vector is faster than the map, since I am building thousands of vectors(or maps) and each vector (map) is relatively small (~10 items). I do not know how to a) make objects sortable by neighborNodeId and b) how to use binary search that searches for a particular member of the class (neighborNodeId). Sorry for the noob question. I am counting on your help.

Comment: You will need a combination of `std::sort()` with a custom Comparator (to sort by the attribute you want) followed by a call to `std::binary_search()` for the value with a custom Comparator to find the required value... docs for both functions are pretty self explanatory..

Comment: Since you have only ~10 items, I would recommend that you also try not sorting at all and using a normal search with std::find.

Comment: Also did you consider using a vector<vector> to find out if a node is a neighbour of another node: if(isNeighbour[i][j] == 1) -> i and j are neighbours. Depend on the number of nodes this can be possible or not from memory perspective. A Hash might also be faster than a map or a binary search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a custom comparator function that takes two `EdgeExtended` objects and compares the fields you're interested in and that you can pass to both `sort` and `binary_search` as a third or fourth argument, respectively.

It can be conveniently done with a lambda function:

```
auto Comp = [](const EdgeExtended& e1, const EdgeExtended& e2)
{
    return e1.neighborNodeId < e2.neighborNodeId;
};
```

If you stuck pre-C++11, write a class with overloaded `operator()` instead:

```
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const EdgeExtended& e1, const EdgeExtended& e2) const
    {
        return e1.neighborNodeId < e2.neighborNodeId;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an exmple for pre-C++11 as well, if you may?

Comment: @AlexandrosE. I may, I didn't have to, but I did it anyway :)

Comment: Thanks my friend. Of course you did not have to. I upvoted and accepted your answer for your trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on jrok's answer, if you encounter similar problems more often, a reusable templated comparator which uses *any member* of a class comes in very handy.

```
template<class T, class U>
class CompareByMember {
    U (T::*mem);          // ugly syntax for member pointer of type U in class T
public:
    CompareByMember(U (T::*mem)) : mem(mem) {}
    bool operator()(const T &a, const T &b) {
        return (a.*mem) < (b.*mem);     // ugly syntax for member pointer access
    }
};
```

As you can see, the syntax for pointers to class members is pretty strange, but once wrapped in this functor you don't have to care about it. One remaining "issue" is that you'd have to write the template parameters `<T, U>` each time you want to use this functor. But using type deduction this problem is solved, introducing a little helper function (note that its name is lower case):

```
template<class T, class U>
CompareByMember<T,U> compareByMember(U (T::*mem)) {
    return CompareByMember<T,U>(mem);
}
```

This results in client code like this:

```
std::vector<EdgeExtended> v = ...;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compareByMember(&EdgeExtended::neighborNodeId));
```

[**Simple demonstration**](http://ideone.com/iQher7)

For member *functions*, a similar templated functor can be written, using the only slightly different member function pointer syntax. You can also overload the call operator in the functor to accept raw pointers of `T` as well as any smart pointer wrapping around `T*` (using templates again).