# How can I pass the whole struct to a function including all elements?

Tags: c++, struct, parameter-passing

I have a structure that I want to pass to a function which will sort the struct. However, I don't know how to pass the WHOLE structure.

What I've done is this until now:

```
void sort_datoteka_sifra(pole &artikli){
}
```

And I call it like `sort_datoteka_sifra(artikli[0])` etc.. but it only passes the [0] elements, I want to pass the whole structure, so that I can use it in the function without having to call artikli[0], artikli[1] and so on in the main function.

Comment: By struct, do you mean array?

Comment: I have a struct called pole, which has several elements and an array declared to the struct. So, yea.. I want to pass the whole array at once not just one by one.

Comment: Is the size of the array fixed at compilation time?

Comment: The the array has maximum size of 100, but the size of it is fixed, inputted by the user in the beginning in separate variable (1 <= array <= 100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. Pass the array as a pointer to its first element as well as the number of elements:

   ```
   void sort_datoteka_sifra(pole *artikli, int count){

   }
   ```

   If `count` is static (known at compile time), you can also pass the array by reference:

   ```
   void sort_datoteka_sifra(pole (&artikli)[100]){

   }
   ```

   If you don't want to hardcode the count, use a function template:

   ```
   template <int N>
   void sort_datoteka_sifra(pole (&artikli)[N]){

   }
   ```
2. Use `std::vector` instead of C-arrays:

   ```
   void sort_datoteka_sifra(std::vector<pole> &artikli){

   }
   ```
3. Use `std::sort` instead of your custom sort function (`#include <algorithms>`) and use it with either your existing C-array or (recommended) a `std::vector`:

   ```
   std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::end(artikli));
   ```

   You have to provide a way to compare two objects; this is done by either overloading `operator<` or by passing a function (or functor) to the sort algorithm:

   ```
   bool comparePole(const pole & a, const pole & b) {
       return /* condition when you want to have a before b */
   }

   std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::end(artikli), &comparePole);
   ```

   If you don't want to write a function and have C++11, you can use a lambda function:

   ```
   std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::end(artikli), [](const pole & a, const pole & b) {
       return /* condition when you want to have a before b */
   });
   ```

   If you want to compare the elements by some member (which has a corresponding `operator<` overload, which is the case for simple types like `int`, `std::string`, etc.), use `compareByMember` from my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616119/592323, e.g. let's say `pole` has an `int ID` by which you want to sort:

   ```
   std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::end(artikli), compareByMember(&pole::ID));
   ```

   To sort a sub-array of size `count`, don't use `std::end` but:

   ```
   std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::begin(artikli) + count, &comparePole);
   ```

Of course you can combine the third option with one of the first two, i.e. provide a sort function which is implemented in terms of `std::sort`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I can't use vectors, it has to be array and the reason I want to pass the whole array to the new function is because I'll be doing the sort inside that function (not my own custom sort, but I'll be using sort() except in a separate function instead of main).

Comment: My recommendation is then to use 1. and to implement the function like in 3.

Comment: @leemes Does sort() will sort all elements in the struct in the correct order as well? (For example, when I sort by ID, the elements of that ID stay in same order)

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but if you provide a compare function which actually compares `a.ID < b.ID` then your elements will have ascending IDs (and the other members of your struct will be moved too of course; as whole struct instances are moved during sorting). For a reusable way to compare "by some member" please also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20616119/592323. If you include those two code snippets in your program, you can write `std::sort(std::begin(artikli), std::begin(artikli) + count, compareByMember(&pole::ID));` This becomes useful if `ID` is not the only member you sort by.

Comment: @leemes I used your first option to pass the array and struct, then I used stable_sort() the same way as you described sort() and it does exactly what I need! :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I recommend `compareByMember` from my linked answer. There is also the option of using lambda functions if you have C++11. I extended part 3. to reflect those two recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Your function requests a reference to a single element. And you obviously also pass only a single element. So, to pass the complete array, you should use a pointer, if it's an array allocated with `new` Or a statically allocated array, e.g.

```
void fun(pole* artikli);
```

Otherwise for C++, it's common to use `std::vector` and pass it by reference:

```
std::vector<pole> artikli;

void fun(std::vector<pole>& artikli);
```

Comment: It's not an array allocated with new. It's just a normal array. `pole artikli[100]`.

Comment: This also applies then.

Comment: True, vector would be very useful in this case, but I'm not allowed to use it. (It's specified in the task to use an array of maximum 100 elements.)

Comment: Ok, then pass it as pointer, as this is what you wanted to do.